# Azure search Indexing data in Collection(Edm.String) attribute

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

Currently, we are building a knowledge base bot using the Bot framework SDK (Question and answer scenario) where we index the data in Azure search, the structure of the index contains searchable Edm.String (de.Microsoft) attributes such as (Plain Text, title) and searchable **Collection(Edm.String)** (de.Microsoft) attributes such as (keywords, product categories and mutual questions).

The mutual questions will be provided by an administrator via a custom UI, so my question is it better to store (index) the mutual questions as they are provided by the admin, or it is better to index the mutual questions after removing stop words/noise words?

As you know the end users who will use the bot will not use the same indexed question(s) as is, they might formulate the question in a different variances, I have done some manual testing and I found scenarios are getting better when the key words are removed, and worse in other cases, I just want to understand what is happening when Azure search query a searchable attribute of data type list of strings.

I’m using **searchMode**: any, and **queryType**: full when sending the search request, below is a sample of how the mutual questions will look before removing the stop words and after removing them.

**Sample 1**

```
"MutualQuestions": [
    "Kann ich im Konto ein individuelles Entgelt anlegen, obwohl es im Produkt keines gibt?",
    "Ich möchte eine andere Zinsberechnungsmethode als im Produkt einstellen."
  ],
  "MutualQuestionsNoNoise": [
    "Konto individuelles Entgelt anlegen, Produkt",
    "Zinsberechnungsmethode Produkt einstellen."
  ]
```

**Sample 2**

```
{
  "MutualQuestions": [
    "Wo binde ich Produkte auf der Internetseite ein?",
    "Wie binde ich Produkte in die Internetseite ein?"
  ],
  "MutualQuestionsNoNoise": [
    "binde Produkte Internetseite"
  ]
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having only key phrases in the sentence can improve search result score. If users search for particular keyword then string with this keyword only will have better score. E.g., if you search for **'weekend trip'** then sentence **'awesome weekend trip'** will have higher score than **'very awesome weekend trip'**. If you're using a [language-specific analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/language-support), stop words for that language will be automatically removed at indexing and search time.

However, as you pointed out, it depends on how users formulate their queries.

[How full text search works in Azure Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-lucene-query-architecture) has good description of different query types and search modes, and how both affect scoring. Note: Collection of strings is treated the same as concatenated string. I.e.: 'awesome trip' is equivalent to ['awesome', 'trip'].

Usually choosing query type and search mode requires some experimentation on representative queries. For your case I would try approach with removing "noise", and using **searchMode=any**. I don't think **queryType** matters a lot in this case. However, it depends on how advanced your users are. If you want to support regex, etc. then **queryType=full** will be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks @yahnoosh & Jacob, so removing stop words (during indexing) and lemmatization is applied even when using de.microsoft (Not English analyzer)? If this is the case then I believe it is better to keep the sentence as is when indexing it (No removal for any word) as well keep the sentence as is when searching for it, right?

Comment: Yes, if you are using analyzer you can keep sentence as it is.

Comment: does that answer your question?